# Discord.py points not loading into json

Tags: python, json, database, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a python point system for my discord and have gotten all the errors and major code straightened out. Now, the <MFR and <MFS commands respond the way they're supposed to, but aren't being reflected in the json.
So for example, I use <MFR and I get "You have gained 1 MF point. You now have 1 MF points"; I use <MFS and I get "You do not have any MF points." The json code stays {"#": {"points": 0}} and if I try <MFR again I get the same message.

If anyone could offer some insight/resources as to how to fix this, that would be very, very appreciated! Thank you.

```
import discord
import json
import os
from discord.ext import commands
from googlesearch import search

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\name")

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="<")

#Bot is online
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    general_chat = client.get_channel(#)

    await general_chat.send("Music Feedback is online.") 

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open ("MF Points.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)
    
    await update_data(users, member)    
        
        
    with open("MF Points.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
    
    
    
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    
    with open ("MF Points.json", "r") as f:
        users = json.load(f)
        
        await update_data(users, message.author)
        await add_points_to_json(users, message.author, message)
        await use_points_from_json(users, message.author, message)
        
        
    with open("MF Points.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
        
async def update_data(users, user):
    if not user.id in users:
        users[user.id] = {}
        users[user.id]["points"] = 0
        
async def add_points_to_json(users, user, message):
    if message.content.startswith("<MFR"):
        points = users[user.id]["points"]
        user_points = points + 1
        await message.channel.send(f"You have gained 1 MF point. You now have {user_points} MF points.")  
        
    with open("MF Points.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)        
async def use_points_from_json(users, user, message):     
    if message.content.startswith("<MFS"):
        points = users[user.id]["points"]
        used_user_points = points - 1         
        if users[user.id]["points"] <= 0:
            await message.channel.send("You do not have any MF points.")
        elif users[user.id]["points"] >= 0:
            await message.channel.send(f"You have used 1 MF point. You now have {used_user_points} MF points.") 
        
    with open("MF Points.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
```

Comment: Why use `discord.ext.commands` if you're not actually creating commands with `@bot.command`? It's a useless import if you're going to check `startswith` on every message.

Comment: I have more written for the code that I've left out :-) along with the from googlesearch import search

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is a very simple issue. On the add_points_to_json you must edit the users object. You fail to do it. You have an empty variable `user_points` that doesn't get saved anywhere.

`users[user.id]["points"] = user_points` will solve this.

```py
async def add_points_to_json(users, user, message):
    if message.content.startswith("<MFR"):
        points = users[user.id]["points"]
        user_points = points + 1
        await message.channel.send(f"You have gained 1 MF point. You now have {user_points} MF points.")  
        users[user.id]["points"] = user_points
    with open("MF Points.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
```

Comment: Thank you! But I'm having trouble following exactly where you're talking about.

Comment: Just tried that and it didn't throw any errors, but it still didn't store the information when I tried <MFR.